# Spring context return again and again instance for singletone class

Tags: spring

Singleton scope in spring means single instance in a Spring context Spring container returns the same instance again and again when I am calling get Bean

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If there was a '?' missing, then the answer is yes - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton